# How to test default access level class in Java without making everything public?

Tags: java, testing, junit

In Swift, to test a default access level class, one can put `@testable` in the test class header, making the internal access level class accessible and testable from the test package, without everything in the class public. I was wondering if Java has a way to access the same purpose?

How can I test a default access level class in Java from the test package without making everything in the class public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are @VisibleForTesting annotations in some java libs, but generally it does not prevent illegal access. Even making package protected does not solve all the issues as still some other classes can use testing code, which can lead to some unexpected behaviour. I recently stumbled upon nice construct that allows you to show the intentions about exposing some methods for tests

```
public class A{
   private int someMethodYouWantToTest(){}

   private Testability testability = new Testability();

   class Testability{
      int exposedMethodForTest(){
          someMethodYouWantToTest()  
      }
   }
}
```

And then in your test class

```
public class Test{
    private A underTest = new A()

   public void testHiddenMethod(){
      a.testability.exposedMethodForTest()
   }
}
```

This way you private method is private, and only access if by dedicated testability inner class that clearly states its purpose, so no one by accident calls your method outside of tests. This solves issues with package protected businness methods that may be called from other places but were really meant to be private.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, the only thing you can do is make things **package protected** if you want them to be used from your test code (that is: if you don't want them to be public).

Example: my classes very often look like

```
class Whatever
  public Whatever() { this(new A(), new B()); };
  Whatever(A a, B b) { ...
```

allowing me to use the second constructor for unit tests that require dependency injection; and at the same time relying on the "convention" that production code should prefer to always use the public constructor.

So even when I have classes that I don't want to be used outside of my package ... i make the constructor public to indicate: use this one please.

The idea is basically that your production code and test code resides in identically-named packages.

In other words: Java doesn't have this nice feature of giving access *only* to test code.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting an answer to a [similar question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/100966/165701)

"

> You generally don't unit test private methods directly. Since they are
>   private, consider them an implementation detail. Nobody is ever going
>   to call one of them and expect it to work a particular way.
>
> You should instead test your public interface. If the methods that
>   call your private methods are working as you expect, you then assume
>   by extension that your private methods are working correctly."

This is equivalent to option 1 in this [link](http://www.artima.com/suiterunner/private2.html)

If 1 does not fit your goals, you can try Approach 2,3 and 4 mentioned in the link

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is not perfect that one has to make methods visible for testing that would otherwise be private, even if it is only in the classes own package.

On the other side, it is anyway recommended (and has many great benefits) not to depend on implementations but on Interfaces.

That means: Give the client an Interface that declares only the methods you want to expose and make the methods you have to test in your implementation protected and do not include them in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

To test default access level classes, which is package private access level, you simple create the test class in the same package, under the test root folder.
Example:

Java root:

```
package com.mycompany.example
class MyProdCodeClass {
  ...
}
```

Test root:

```
package com.mycompany.example
class MyProdCodeClassTest {
  ...
}
```